# Emacs 24.5.1 on Windows: How to use server mode?

Tags: microsoft-windows, server, emacs-daemon

I used to have Emacs 25.xx on my windows pc and was very happy with the daemon/server mode of emacs. Emacs started via batch-script on startup and everything worked fine -- on every subsequent call Emacs just started instantly. Just as it should. :-)

However, due to scrolling problems in AucTeX I went back to 24.5.1. Now Emacs doesn't start in server mode.

I found http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Emacs_server and it says at the bottom that on Microsoft Windows you need to have at least Emacs version 25 to use the server mode.

Is this just outdated information? Is there really no way to run Emacs 24 in server mode on Windows? Has anyone of you experience with running Emacs in server mode on Windows?

If that's important: I use Windows 10. Thanks in advance for any input on that topic.

Comment: I never had much luck with --daemon on WIndows, but have used `(server-start)` in my init file and emacsclient for years with various versions. Perhaps you could just have Emacs run minimized at startup and achieve the same result?

Comment: Are your problems with scrolling related to `(display-graphic-p)`? When you start up Emacs as a server it might have that function return nil, so you might have problems with any extension that has some features that require a graphic display to work. I had to do [this](https://github.com/DoMiNeLa10/.emacs/blob/master/.emacs.d/config/platform-specific.el#L11) to get `web-mode` to work properly when I use Emacs as a server.

Comment: gnuclient is another alternative, comes from xemacs but perhaps more compatible with windows.

Answer (score 5):

Add the following code to your `init.el`.

```
(require 'server)
(unless (server-running-p)
  (cond
   ((eq system-type 'windows-nt)
    (setq server-auth-dir "~\\.emacs.d\\server\\"))
   ((eq system-type 'gnu/linux)
    (setq server-auth-dir "~/.emacs.d/server/")))
  (setq server-name "emacs-server-file")
  (server-start))
```

Then you can get access to server with `emacsclientw.exe` in the `bin/` directory under your emacs installation path.

Comment: Okay, I start emacs with: "...\emacs\bin\emacsclientw.exe" --alternate-editor="...\emacs\bin\runemacs.exe" -c. But now I get an error message saying: "...\bin\emacsclientw.exe: connect: A connection could not be established, because the target computer refused the connection." (I have a german error message, this is just a translation)

Comment: Okay, the error message is really clear. I just checked if my startup scripts (they just start emacs with --daemon argument) have an effect. They don't. Emacs 24 doesn't create a background process anymore, I can see it in the task-manager. So of course emacsclientw.exe cannot connect to a server. But even if I manually start a server with `M-x + "start-server"` nothing happens. Am I missing something? :-(

Comment: @Micha90 When you call `server-start` there is no added background process; emacsclient connects to the foreground one. However if you set `server-name` to a non-default value as suggested in this answer, you have to tell emacsclient about it as well.

Comment: I've used `(server-start)` on Windows without having to set the auth dir or name -- things should work fine with the defaults. As noted already the `--daemon` option is not supported prior to Emacs 25 and there is no background process, but you can launch Emacs, call `server-start`, and connect using `emacsclientw`. You can set the `ALTERNATE_EDITOR` environment variable or have a startup task launch Emacs, depending on whether you want it always running or launched on first invocation.

Comment: I had the same socket problem after using `server-start`, and when I checked the server-name variable it seems emacs(?) had auto-populated it with something. Mine was `server4488`. After adding that to my command line, clientw could connect.

Answer (score 1):

I can verify that it is possible to run Emacs 24 as a daemon on Windows 10, if you use [Cygwin](http://cygwin.org/).  If you're using the Windows-native Cygwin version (Cygwin package `emacs-w32`), then I think you'll need to start the daemon through bash, but you can call `emacsclient` directly from Windows, and the resulting instances will connect to the daemon just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had problem using emacsclient to open a file. The reason ended up being Windows firewall blocking the connection to server since my account is admin.